# Test git branch local webserver

Tags: php, git, deployment

I have a PHP application in my web root folder (for example: `/www/project/`). I want to use git with my project, but I'm very confused about its utility. For example:

If I create a branch `NewContactPage`, then I've two branches: `master` and `NewContactPage`. I do some changes on a file contact.php (for example) but where can I test this change and compare it with the `master` contact.php file? I only have one webroot folder.

Do I have to archive all my projects to the other webroot folder if I want to test some new feature? Really?!

================ EDIT UPDATE QUESTION ======

I think I didn't explain it very well. I'll try another example.

My local development environment has one Apache web server, where the webroot is `/user/12345/project/www` ok?

In this directory, I've got my project (with git), and for example, my principal branch is `develop`. So when I go to `http://localhost` I can see the index.php for `develop`, ok?

Well, say I follow the git-flow best practices and for example, I've to create a branch with a new feature, and that has a new contact.php page. So I create the branch `contactNEW` and in this branch, I edit contact.php with some code.

So, if I go to `http://localhost/contact.php` (for example) I will see the new change (branch `contactNEW`). Now if I want to visually compare (with the web browser) the two files (develop/contact.php and contactNEW/contact.php) for example in order to see, say a button's color, what to do?

I've to copy all the branch `develop` files to a new web root folder? Or is it better to copy all branch `contactNEW` files to another webroot (Virtual Hostost for example) for Apache?

I suppose that I've to commit or undo the commit over the repository and then refresh the web browser, no?

Answer (score 1):

If you use git for a web application and need to have a different "testing / staging" area, that means that you have:

- Two working directories; each of them a complete `git` repository linked by "remotes".
- Two entries in your web server configuration, say, with two different ports. Each of them pointing to one of thw two directories. This way you can test your development in one of the web servers while at the same time having your production version up. (Note: this is not meant to necessarily be the "real" production web server that your clients use, just a version of the "production code" so you can compare your changes to that).

Of course, this can scale arbitrarily. For example, if you have several developers, it makes sense for everyone of them have a separate web server (port) to surf in his own development (along with their separat `git` repository of course).

As long as everything is local and you do not need to "deploy" your application over company/network boundaries, that's really all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I follow, but yes only one branch at a time can be "checked out" in a given working copy. But it is easy enough to switch branches:

```
git checkout NewContactPage
{do some testing}
git checkout master
```

Additionally, copies of git repositories are cheap and trivial to create. Plain old `cp -r <repo> <repo-copy>` (assuming a UNIX derivative here) is up to the task. You can then check out a branch in repo-copy and delete it when you're done.

To compare your contact.php file between branches (regardless of the checked-out branch in this formulation of the command):

```
git diff master NewContactPage contact.php
```

Comment: The `cp` advice is true, it works; I would suggest switching that to `git clone` though so he can `git push` his changes to his primary repos when he's done.